# Overlapping ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Here the top text hides and the list of scrollView overlaps the text. While Scrolling the scrollview hides the text behind in top part. Here is my code which overlaps the text on the top. Can you help me to rectify it? While scrolling my top text should not be hidden or overlapped.My scrollview should scroll under the top text. I have attached the image which is overlapped

```
![screenshot][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lnJH.png

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:title="Doctor Appointment"
            app:titleTextColor="#fff"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_logout"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/myToolbar"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_border"
                android:text="save"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_border"
                android:text="close"
                android:textColor="@color/blue" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/G1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/R1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="By Speciality" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/R2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="By Doctor" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Dr J. Anitha Ponmalar Reg.No: "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_calendar"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="1 November 2021"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/G11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/R11"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AM" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/R12"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PM" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
                    android:text="12:00"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="263dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
                    android:text="12:15"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="263dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:text="12:30"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="303dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:text="12:45"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="303dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
                    android:text="01:00"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="343dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
                    android:text="01:15"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="343dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
                    android:text="01:30"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="383dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
                    android:text="01:45"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="383dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
                    android:text="02:00"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="423dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
                    android:text="02:15"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="423dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
                    android:text="02:30"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="463dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
                    android:text="02:45"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="463dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
                    android:text="03:00"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="503dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
                    android:text="03:15"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="503dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
                    android:text="03:30"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="543dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
                    android:text="03:45"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="543dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="580dp"
                    android:text="04:00"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="583dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="580dp"
                    android:text="04:15"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="583dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="620dp"
                    android:text="04:30"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="623dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="620dp"
                    android:text="04:45"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </TextView>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="623dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_green"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                </Button>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow won't solve your problem. We might help you with that, but you need to show any effort. Post any code and what have you tried to do so far

Comment: Please post your Code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can give an id to your top part and then you can use ```android:layout_below="id/your_top_parts_id"``` in your ```ScrollView``` that should fix it. or any other similar property like that. Try this and let me know. @Suji

Comment: android:layout_below="id/your_top_parts_id" this doesn't work. No changes shows while adding the layout below.